# Iterative Algorithms

Tags: mapreduce, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I know that k-means algorithm is iterative. If we want to run it using MapReduce, whole the input data must be reloaded and reprocessed in each iteration, which increases communication cost. But my question is that whether DBSCAN and SCAN are also iterative like k-means and k-medoid?

Comment: Look at the algorithms. What is your guess and why? P.S. being non-iterative does not at all mean it is easier to parallelize the algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the reload, maybe you may try using Spark which allows to cache intermidiate result dropping down the time to process your data compared to Hadoop MapReduce.

DBSCAN needs the computations of the neighbors of almost each node, which is in fact quite expensive when we speak about big data.

Implementing well DBSCAN on such a system is really complex and it has been done with Spark [here](https://github.com/alitouka/spark_dbscan). However I do believe that iterative algorithms are much more efficient usign Spark than others like DBSCAN.